Web Sockets Socket.IO + React multiple screens for each user problem
(Hope someone could help me) I'm developing a Web Sockets game (similar to Pong) with Express for backend and React for frontend. I'm currently facing some trouble trying to give each user his own screen. Here's my code:
function Home() {
const { users, absoluteScreen } = HomeFunctions();
const userRefs = useRef([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
        const cursorPosition = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };
        socketManager.updateCursorPosition(cursorPosition);

    };

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    };
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    users.forEach((user, index) => {
        if (userRefs.current[index]) {
            userRefs.current[index].scrollLeft = user.board.position.x;
        }
    });

}, [users]);


return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', overflowX: 'hidden', width: '100%' }}>
        {users.map((user, index) => (
            <div
                ref={el => userRefs.current[index] = el}
                key={index}
                style={{
                    flex: '0 0 auto',
                    width: user.board.width,
                    height: '100vh',
                    overflow: 'hidden',
                    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                    position: 'relative'
                }}
            >
                <div
                    style={{
                        position: 'absolute',
                        left: user.cursorPosition?.x || 0,
                        top: user.cursorPosition?.y || 0,
                    }}
                >
                    <p
                        style={{
                            transform: 'translate(-50%, 350%)',
                        }}
                    >
                        {user.nickName}
                    </p>
                    <img
                        src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/120030275?v=4"
                        alt="test"
                        style={{
                            transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
                            width: "80px",
                            height: "80px"
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
);

}
(The part that handles the cursorPosition doesn't matter, just for context)
So, what I'm trying to do is that each user just can see his part of the screen (backend calcs the position of each board for each user, like this):
    calculatePositions() {
    let currentX = 0;

    this.users.forEach(user => {
        user.board.position = { x: currentX, y: 0 };
        currentX += user.board.width;
    });

    return { width: currentX, height: 600 };
}

And the screens are displaying one beside the other correctly (due the scrollLeft):

But right now I haven't find a way to make each user moves (not manually) his view to his part of the board cause currently just can see the first user screen. I have tried using ScrollIntoView function but not getting good results. I was thinking in a pass to each user just his information approach from the server but I'm new on sockets and I must find a way to do it. If anyone could help me bringing some light on this I'll really appreciate it.
PD: If I let the scroll enable I can see both users, so user screen is placing correctly, but can't find how to move his view to his part.

